# How to diff two file lists and ignoring place in list

Tags: unix, diff

I have two lists of files which I want to diff.
The second list has more files in it, and because they are all in alphabetical order when I diff these two lists I get files (lines) that exists in both lists, but in a different place.

I want to diff these two lists, ignoring line place in the list.
This way I would get only the new or missing lines in the list.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the example you quotes @Sparr

`a` contains

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

`b` contains

```
a.txt
a1.txt
b.txt
b2.txt
```

`diff a b` gives

```
1a2
> a1.txt
3c4
< c.txt
---
> b2.txt
```

What is it about this output that does not meet your needs?

Comment: I Have two lists. First:
a
b
c
1

Second:
1
a
b
c

These lists should be identical but they are not according to diff.

Comment: But your question says that they are both in alphabetical order, the example you have just given they are not - which is it? If you need them in alphabetical order, then sort them using `sort`.

Comment: You are correct. Once I ran the sort command on both of the files it worked as I expected.
Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

You can try this approach which involves "subtracting" the two lists as follows:

```
$ cat file1
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt

$ cat file2
a.txt
a1.txt
b.txt
b2.txt
```

1) print everything in file2 that is not in file1 i.e. file2 - file1

```
$ grep -vxFf file1 file2
a1.txt
b2.txt
```

2) print everything in file1 that is not in file2  i.e. file1 - file2

```
$ grep -vxFf file2 file1
c.txt
```

(You can then do what you want with these diffs e.g. write to file, sort etc)

grep options descriptions:

```
  -v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
  -x, --line-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole lines
  -F, --fixed-strings       PATTERN is a set of newline-separated strings
  -f, --file=FILE           obtain PATTERN from FILE
```

Comment: This works, but using cat and grep takes a very long time.
I have many files and it can take up to an hour.

Comment: You don't need to use `cat`, just `grep`. The `cat` was only to illustrate the contents of the files.

Comment: This would not work in the case where some files were sub-strings of the other. Also as the filenames will be treated as regular expressions the `.` character will be treated as any character - so `a1.txt` would match `a1ttxt`.

Comment: added the -F flag to treat them as fixed-strings instead of regular expressions.

Comment: Awesome! I used this to generate my pip requirements.txt `pip freeze -l | grep -vxFf dev-requirements.txt - > requirements.txt`

Answer (score 16):

Do the following:

cat file1 file2 | sort | uniq -u

This will give you a list of lines which are unique (ie, not duplicated).

Explanation:
        1) cat file1 file2 will put all of the entries into one list
        2) sort will sort the combined list
        3) uniq -u will only output the entries which don't have duplicates

Comment: Wow, this is really good. This should 100% be the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

#### The deft command to use here is the humble *`comm`* command:

To demonstrate, let's create two input files:

```
$ cat <<EOF >a
> a.txt
> b.txt
> c.txt
> EOF

$ cat <<EOF >b
> a.txt
> a1.txt
> b.txt
> b2.txt
> EOF
```

Now, using the `comm` command to get what the question wanted:

```
$ comm -2 a b
        a.txt
        b.txt
c.txt
```

This shows a *columnar output* with **missing** files (lines in `a` but not in `b`) in the first column and **extra** files (lines in `b` but not in `a`) in the second column.

#### What exactly does *`comm`* do?

Here's the output if the command is typed without any switches:

```
$ comm a b
                a.txt
        a1.txt
                b.txt
        b2.txt
c.txt
```

This shows *three columns* thus:

1. Lines in `a` but not in `b`
2. Lines in both `a` and `b`
3. Lines in `b` but not in `a`

What the numbered switches `-123` do is it *hides* the specified column from the output.

So for example:

- Specifying `-13` results in common lines only
- Specifying `-12` results in lines only in `b`
- Specifying `-23` results in lines only in `a`
- Specifying `-2` results in the symmetric difference
- Specifying `-123` results in no output

Comment: What a great find this `comm` command is! This gave me exactly what I was looking for in that I wanted to know not only which entries existed in only one of the files regardless of order (like OP) but also I wanted to filter on results from one of the files (like an array subtraction without needing to build an array). A hidden gem of a command for sure. Probably hidden due to its not so obvious name?

Comment: I agree, this is a gem of a command. Given that it's part of GNU Coreutils, I think this should be selected as the correct answer. While input should still be sorted first, it's simpler than messing around with uniq, sort, and diff.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting the two list before you diff them will provide a more useful diff data.

Comment: The lists are already sorted in alphabetical order.
And that is the base of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are sorted, diff should catch the insertions and deletions just fine and only report the differences.

Comment: Let me explain
I have two lists. The first one:
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt

The second:
a.txt
a1.txt
b.txt
b2.txt

The wanted diff would be:
a1.txt
b2.txt
c.txt

How can I sort the lists if they are already sorted alphabeticallly?